# Why did Strelitzia transform in Episode 15?

Tags: darling-in-the-franxx

In episode 15 we can see that after re-uniting with Zero Two, Hiro when connects with her

> Strelizia jumps up in the air to transform into a red version of the FranXX while emitting a bright light, mid-air while transforming 
>  [image: red strelizia]

Why did this sudden change in the FranXX take place?

The only possible reason I can think of is the newly mutual acceptance of each other that made this happen. Are there any canon reasons for it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no real explanation however:

> In ep 15 she accepts herself for what it is after the talk with Hiro. As we know she is originally red skinned.

Further evidence:

> When Klaxosaur Princess used Strelitzia it turned blue as well.